# Adobe AIR app with ALIPAY

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, alipay

we are developing an application for adobe air with in-app purchase
(of game add-ons).
we need to implement alipay inside the app.
I downloaded their documentations, it looks like there is no native extension for air. 
i thought about using it with php + StageWebView (to show their UI for user paument) . 
anyone here has an experience with Alipay + AS3?

Answer (score 0):

Create an API on your own server that maps to the Alipay API or just hit the Alipay API directly. You shouldn't use a `StageWebView` for anything more than displaying a simple page since you have absolutely no control over it and cannot retrieve any data or response from the browser in your AS3.

If you are planning to upload this to the iOS App Store, you can't use Alipay. You **must** use Apple's In-App Purchase system. If you don't, Apple will reject your app. I don't know about the Google Play Store off the top of my head, but I believe it is recommended you do the same though not currently enforced the way Apple does. Additionally, it is natively supported and what users expect when using an Android or iOS device. There are various AIR Native Extensions (ANE) that you can use to implement that (just do some searching and you should find some)

Comment: I'm not using that for IOS or GooglePlay. i'm uploading the app to chinese app stores that apparantly use Alipay for in-app purchases.
I do need some way to display their password and credit-card billing page inside the app (since they dont have a native extension).